# Spark - Load jar based on spark version

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, jar

We want to load the `org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.12` package for our spark jobs, in a version agnostic way.

Some people are using spark 3.1.2, and others are using 3.2.0.

For the ones on 3.1.2, I need to load:

```
org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.12:3.1.2
```

For the ones on 3.2.0, I need to load:

```
org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.12:3.2.0
```

Is there a generic mechanism I can implement to load the correct jar based on the spark version, without requiring my users to do anything on their end?

I don't mind saving all versions of the jars locally, and adding them via `--jars` or `spark.jars`. The problem is selecting the correct jar based on the user's spark version.

For full context, I'd like to configure this for use with `pytest-spark`.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with, in a `pytest-spark` context, though should be generally applicable:

```py
@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def spark_session(request, spark_conf):
    from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
    import pytest_spark

    spark_conf = pytest_spark.SparkConfigBuilder().get()
    spark_home = pytest_spark.SparkHome(pytest_config=request.config)
    spark_version = re.findall('^Spark (\d+\.\d+\.\d+)', spark_home.version)[0]

    jars = spark_conf.get('spark.jars.packages')
    jars = set(jars.split(',')) if jars else set()
    jars.add(f'org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.12:{spark_version}')
    spark_conf.set('spark.jars.packages', ",".join(list(jars)))

    session = SparkSession.builder \
        .config(conf=spark_conf) \
        .getOrCreate()

    logger = session.sparkContext._jvm.org.apache.log4j
    logger.LogManager.getLogger("org").setLevel(logger.Level.OFF)
    logger.LogManager.getLogger("akka").setLevel(logger.Level.OFF)

    yield session
    session.stop()
```